# JSON parse error incorrect character

Tags: json, parsing

I'm new to using JSON and I can't figure out why I have this error.

Here is a simple JSON statement:

```
var resu = JSON.parse("[{'Tourney':{'clubID':'5801133T','tourneyID':'TPP27082014S','Title':'Mon petit tournoi'}}]");
```

When I run it it says "Incorrect character"...

I tried without the enclosing brackets [].
I tried escaping the quotes like this: /'clubID/':/'5801133T/'..

Same error.

Any clue welcome.

Comment: I didn't know that JSON has its own parser -- I thought you had to use some sort of programming language.

Comment: http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON requires double quotes around strings:

```
var resu = JSON.parse("{\"Tourney\":{\"clubID\":\"5801133T\",\"tourneyID\":\"TPP27082014S\",\"Title\":\"Mon petit tournoi\"}}");
```

Answer (score 0):

proper JSON format requires double quotes. the below should fix it.

```
var resu = JSON.parse("[{\"Tourney\":{\"clubID\":\"5801133T\",\"tourneyID\":\"TPP27082014S\",\"Title\":\"Mon petit tournoi\"}}]");
```